# Spring Data создание сущностей в бд

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Добрый день! Есть две сущности, связаные между собой 1к1. Необходимо сделать так, что бы удалять с дочерней(Д) было запрещено, а удалив с родительськой(Р) автоматически происходило удаление с дочерней сущности. Использую `Spring Data`
На данный момент создает 2 таблицы: Р - без внешнего ключа на Д, и Д - с внешним ключем на Р + поле `Р_id` , но ключ создается с `On DELETE RESTRICT`. Т.е. ключ на Д должен создаваться `On delete cascade`,  а на таблице Р должен быть ключ на таблицу Д с `On DELETE RESTRICT`. СУБД : MYsql 5.6.14

Сущность Дочерняя:

```
  @Entity
public class Contacts {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE , orphanRemoval = true)
    private Agent agent;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Родительская:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agents")
public class Agent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "agent" , cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE , orphanRemoval = true)
    private Contacts contact;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну просто измениете в дочерней restrict на cascade

Comment: в бд то понятно как изменить. хочу что бы Java при создании таблиц сама проставляла On Delete Cascade

Comment: насколько я знаю, если пометить их как игр, то удалив родительский объект все привязанные тоже удалятся. но не используйте этот метод. это просто костыльный план Б.